# how to read n number lines from console?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Read all lines from console and store in A collection. in this context how to use scanner's methods. The number of lines user may enter is unknown.

Comment: What have you tried till now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        String s = reader.nextLine();
        if (s.equals("!q")) {
            break;
        }
        a.add(s);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your clarification, But we need to place one or another condition to break the loop correct?

Comment: I've edited my response, now if you want to quit to loop you just need to write "!q" in new line.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
import java.util.*;  
public class ScannerClassExample1 {    
      public static void main(String args[]){                       
          String s = "Hello, This is JavaTpoint.";  
          //Create scanner Object and pass string in it  
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(s);  
          //Check if the scanner has a token  
          System.out.println("Boolean Result: " + scan.hasNext());  
          //Print the string  
          System.out.println("String: " +scan.nextLine());  
          scan.close();           
          System.out.println("--------Enter Your Details-------- ");  
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  
          System.out.print("Enter your name: ");    
          String name = in.next();   
          System.out.println("Name: " + name);           
          System.out.print("Enter your age: ");  
          int i = in.nextInt();  
          System.out.println("Age: " + i);  
          System.out.print("Enter your salary: ");  
          double d = in.nextDouble();  
          System.out.println("Salary: " + d);         
          in.close();           
          }    
}
```

and output will be like:

```
Boolean Result: true
String: Hello, This is JavaTpoint.
-------Enter Your Details--------- 
Enter your name: Abhishek
Name: Abhishek
Enter your age: 23
Age: 23
Enter your salary: 25000
Salary: 25000.0
```

Comment: thanks but i want to do it in a loop continuously. And i got solution.